# How to handle empty fields during searching / filtering data?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, search, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm struggling with data searching algorithm, which has to retrieve some data from the database using multiple fields. Each textbox provides a given parameter, stored in the database, accessed by Entity Framework. It's working when I enter data to all fields but if I leave any field empty it doesn't retrieve any record.
My question is - How to handle empty fields. If I leave any field without data, it should just not consider this parameter during selecting from the database and select data basing on non-null parameters.

This is what I've created so far:

```
   [HttpPost]
   public ViewResult Search(string brand, string model, int? manufactDateMin,
       int? manufactDateMax, int? priceMin, int? priceMax, int? engineCapMin,
       int? engineCapMax, string engineType, int page = 1)
   {

       IEnumerable<Car> foundItems = repository.Cars
           .Where(c => brand == null || c.Brand == brand)
           .Where(c => model == null || c.Model == model)
           .Where(c => manufactDateMin == null || manufactDateMax == null || (c.ManufactDate.Year >= manufactDateMin) && (c.ManufactDate.Year < manufactDateMax))
           .Where(c => priceMin == null || priceMax == null || (c.Price >= priceMin) && (c.Price < priceMax))
           .Where(c => engineCapMin == null || engineCapMax == null || (c.EngineCapacity >= engineCapMin) && (c.EngineCapacity < engineCapMax))
           .Where(c => engineType == null || c.EngineType == engineType)
           .OrderBy(c => c.Id)
           .Skip(PageSize * (page - 1))
           .Take(PageSize);

       CarListViewModel VMmodel = new CarListViewModel
       {
           Cars = foundItems,
           PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
           {
               CurrentPage = page,
               ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
               TotalItems = foundItems.Count(),
           },
           CarType = null
       };

       return View("List", VMmodel);
   }
```

Comment: instead of variable == null, in the strings, try to use, string.IsNullOrEmpty(variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use a new where statement for each comparison. combine them into one.  separate them into a new line for readability. Also, your parameters are defined as strings but your comparing it to null.  You will have to pass a null for this to work.  If you are passing the contents of a textbox or something then the string will be "" and not a null.

```
.Where(c => brand == "" || c.Brand == brand) &&
       (model == "" || c.Model == model) &&
       ((manufactDateMin == null || manufactDateMax == null || (c.ManufactDate.Year >= manufactDateMin) && (c.ManufactDate.Year < manufactDateMax)) &&
       (priceMin == null || priceMax == null || (c.Price >= priceMin) && (c.Price < priceMax))) &&
       (engineCapMin == null || engineCapMax == null || (c.EngineCapacity >= engineCapMin) && (c.EngineCapacity < engineCapMax))) &&
       (engineType == "" || c.EngineType == engineType))
```

Comment: I'd argue that multiple `Where` statements is more readable than one giant `Where` call.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do it separately like this

```
IQueryable<Car> query  = repository.Cars;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(brand))
{
 query = query.Where(x => x.Brand  == brand);
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model ))
{
 query = query.Where(x => x.Model == model );
}
```

and after all of them you put the take and skyp, it is faster and more readable